# How to config an SSH connection with travis ci?

Tags: java, docker, ssh, travis-ci, ssh-keys

I'm trying to setup a travis ci configuration for a docker project and I'm stuck on the ssh connection to my server in my .travis.yml. I can't find the yml file of this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xLWDOLhTH38&ab_channel=DevOpsJourney, I already added my ssh private key to the travis ci settings, and my current working .travis.yml file is:

```
arch:
  - amd64

env:
  - IMGNAME=myImageName

language: java

services:
  - docker

before_install:
  - mvn clean install
  - docker build -t ${IMGNAME} .

script:
  - echo test

after_success:
  - docker login -u ${DHUB_USERNAME} -p ${DHUB_PASSWORD}
  - echo test
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you are trying to accomplish? Do you want to be able to ssh into the running build agent?

Comment: No, like it's explained in the YouTube video, I'm trying to configure a CI/CD for a docker application running on a server (Test and deploy).

Answer (score 0):

I did this after a lot of try and test, I am very happy that it's working like I wanted but I'm sure that it's not so good.

1. Create your Travis CI account
2. Enable the connection with your Github repositories
3. Add the *.travis.yml* file to the src directory of your project (which should be also your git repo, but you can edit it if you want)
4. Since we will deploy a docker project we need to test if the docker build works before deploy. Here the deployment will be on our private server, this is why we need to connect to our server with SSH from the Travis servers.
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzFMx.png)

   1. I didn't know that even if you had an SSH key you can't connect to a server if there is a firewall rule that is blocking you. So if your docker app has to connect to any server, don't forget to add the Travis server's IP addresses to the whitelist (firewall rules) of those servers (from your host provider platform or your server command line). To find the current IP addresses of the Travis CI servers ➢ https://dnsjson.com/nat.travisci.net/A.json
   2. For the SSH key, after generating your key, add it to the authorized keys of your server

```
// From your (windows, I don't know how it is for other OS but I think that it is pretty the same) computer execute this command to generate your SSH key,
// to make it in pem format which is needed for the travis ci ssh key format,
// accept all default paramaters, no paraphrase (travis doesn't like it),
// and for the location paramater also (you can change it if you want)

ssh-keygen -m PEM -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"

// Inside your server execute this command
// this will add your SSH key to your server authorized SSH keys
type $env:USERPROFILE\.ssh\id_rsa.pub | ssh [user]@[yourServerIP] "cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys"
```

3. Now your private key is inside the id_rsa file and your public key is inside the id_rsa.pub

   1. ***cat /id_rsa***
   2. copy and paste it to the Travis ci SSH key config of your project ([https://travis-ci.com/github/[githubUserName]/[github_repo]/settings](https://travis-ci.com/github/%5BgithubUserName%5D/%5Bgithub_repo%5D/settings))
   3. ***cat /id_rsa.pub***
   4. copy and paste it to the deploy key of your github project settings
   5. Now the SSH agent of Travis will do the work for you
4. inside your .travis.yml:

```
arch:
  - amd64

language: java #Default install Gradle, Maven, Ant
sudo: true # ./mvnw ==> for the permission denied error 

services:
  - docker

before_install:
  - chmod +x mvnw # ./mvnw ==> for the permission denied error

script:
  - mvn clean install # not sure if it's useful before a docker build
  - docker build -t ${DHUB_TAG} .

after_success:
  - eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
  #- chmod 600 ./deploy_key ==> don't need that anymore
  - echo -e "Host ${SERVER_IP_ADDRESS}\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n" >> ~/.ssh/config
  #- ssh-add ./deploy_key ==> don't need that anymore
  - ssh ${SERVER_USER}@${SERVER_IP_ADDRESS} "
    cd ${WORK_FOLDER} &&
    git config user.name ${GITHUB_USERNAME} &&
    git config user.email ${GITHUB_EMAIL} &&
    git pull 'https://${GITHUB_USERNAME}:${GITHUB_PASSWORD}@github.com/${GITHUB_REPO}' production &&
    git config --unset-all user.name &&
    git config --unset-all user.email &&
    sudo apt update &&
    sudo apt install maven &&
    mvn clean install &&
    docker login -u ${DHUB_USERNAME} -p ${DHUB_PASSWORD} &&
    docker build -t ${DHUB_TAG} . &&
    docker push ${DHUB_TAG} &&
    docker pull ${DHUB_TAG} &&
    docker stop ${DOCKER_CONTAINER_NAME} || true && docker rm ${DOCKER_CONTAINER_NAME} || true &&
    docker run -p 8080:8080 --name=${DOCKER_CONTAINER_NAME} -d ${DHUB_TAG}"
```

- To add your ${params} go to your project settings
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/442TX.png)
- A little walkthrough of what it's not explained on the file

  - Make ***arch: amd64*** ==> select the CPU architectures
  - ***services: docker*** ==> will launch the docker service
  - After the SSH connection was made

    - update the git repo
    - ***mvn clean install*** for the target folder and jar
    - build your docker image push it to docker hub
    - pull it and run it
    - the "docker stop ${DOCKER_CONTAINER_NAME} || true && docker rm ${DOCKER_CONTAINER_NAME} || true" ==> if the docker container doesn't exist

Also, you can add ${anyValue} to the Travis settings if you want them to be hidden in Travis ci logs.

Thanks for your time.